# Jquery form not submitting or validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following form validation and submission script in jquery but for some reason its not working. It looks like its submitting but when i click submit it just resets the form and it doesn't validato or do the ajax post. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong here?

## MODIFIED CODE

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
        $("#form").validate({debug: false,
                             rules: {
                               name: "required",
                               email: {
                                 required: true,
                                 email: true
                               },
                               phone: {
                                 required: true,
                                 phone: true
                               }
                             },
                             messages: {
                               name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                               email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
                               phone: "Please provide a valid phone number.",
                             },
                             submitHandler: function() {  

                             // Send the request
                             $.post('/submit.php', {
                               name: $('#name').val(),
                               email: $('#email').val(),
                               phone: $('#phone').val(),
                               message: $('#message').val()
                             }, function(d){
                               alert("Thank you for submitting your request someone will contact your shortly.");
                             }); 
                           }

        });
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` You're not preventing the default action of a submit which is a postback. The postback causes the page to reload. Prevent the action. I'm sure the validation is probably running but the page reloads before you could see the validation errors appear.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
   ....
   return false; 
});
```

to the end of the submit, this will avoid executing the actual submit of the form.

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out by Dustin, preventDefault might be better if you don't want to stop your event from bubbling up..

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
   ....
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: return false will work, but has drawbacks - it is better to use e.preventDefault() at the beginning of the method. See http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: or `e.preventDefault();`. Either works but I think `preventDefault()` is the preferred method.

Comment: I updated my code with that and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I switched your code a bit, seems you using jquery validate?, their documents have the correct way to submit a form. http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#too-much-recursion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                    },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phone: true
                    }
                },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            phone: "Please provide a valid phone number.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {  
                  // Stop the form actually posting
                   e.preventDefault();

                 // Send the request
               $.post('/submit.php', {
               name: $('#name').val(),
               email: $('#email').val(),
               phone: $('#phone').val(),
               message: $('#message').val()
               }, function(d){
                    alert("Thank you for submitting your request someone will contact your shortly.");
               }); 
        }

});
```

Comment: I tried adding that submitHandler: function(form)  as well in my code and it didn't help, man im going crazy according to all the documentation it seems like im doing it right but it never works

Comment: I prefer using $.ajax instead of post or get, for waht ia worth.

Comment: I tired that but i get the same results